# how to define stair-like position to several plane objects?

Tags: modeling

I have some objects that are plane, I want to transform it into a stair-shaped order, like: object 0 - Z: 0.01
object 1 - Z: 0.02
object 3 - Z: 0.03

but without having to do it manually, I can't use the array because they are different objects

Comment: Remember to make your stairs ergonomic. :) https://www.calculator.net/stair-calculator.html

Comment: @Markus Hey thanks, that's actually really helpful :)

Answer (score 6):

**Via the UI:**

Some variation on this one, which has  all  steps in XY plane, and a top-step target vertex set up, ready?

- Pivot: 3D cursor, at bottom step
- Snap: To: 'Vertex' With: 'Active', and set to affect 'Scale'
- Header Options: Affect only Locations

All steps selected, top step active, <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> .. <kbd>Y</kbd> to set the axis, Shear the objects' locations a lttle.

Once a regular stagger is achieved, <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>  scale them, with snap, to the target.

[image]

I don't think the *Shear* axes are what they claim to be in the manual, so there may be some playing required. This shear is executed in Global space, Main axis 'Z', Ortho, 'Y'.

Comment: Lol, seeing this made me realize sorting in step direction order makes more sense than name.

Comment: @batFINGER.. :) .. I can't make the manual's axis claims make sense, so it may even be worth scripting the shear, to avoid messing about.

Comment: Depends somewhat on clarification from OP I suppose. The small step size (and prob caught up in my simple test just put planes in same loc and "wafer-ed" them)

Comment: I ended up finding a simpler way... duplicate the object, position the duplicate at the desired point and press shift + R... it will create other objects with distance points between the original and the duplicate

Comment: @user116840 For sure! (But your OP _did_  say you started with a bunch of objects in a plane )  If yours is a better answer for you, you should go ahead, post, and accept your own answer. (I'll make sure it gets at least one +1) :)

Answer (score 4):

you can do it like this:

1. create a collection named "Automatic"
2. move all objects in it
3. run script
4. enjoy

   ```
    import bpy

    index = bpy.data.collections.find('Automatic')

    if index != -1:

        coll = bpy.data.collections[index]

        if coll != -1: 

            z = 0.01

            for eachObject in coll.objects:

                eachObject.location[2] = z
                z = z + 0.01
   ```

Comment: Question re the usage of  `find` in last few answers.. Running `D.collections.find("Foo")` on default file returns -1. `D.collections[-1]` is `bpy.data.collections['Collection 1']` _ie_ the last item in a list.  Would recommend testing against -1 or using `get(name)` and testing against `None`.

Comment: @batFINGER: thanks, adapted my answer

Comment: `if index != -1:`  (and prob put `coll = .. ` line in if block)

Comment: @batFINGER: thanks, adapted again ;)

Comment: is giving error

Comment: Did you check your indentation?

Answer (score 4):

**Sort the planes**

Assuming that the planes have default names *eg* "Plane", "Plane.001", ... (in step order) can sort by the name and set the $z$ location accordingly. Have absolutely set by order, to transform use `location += d`

```
import bpy

delta = 1

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene 

planes = sorted(
        (
            o for o in scene.objects
            if o.name.startswith("Plane")
        ),
        key = lambda o : o.name
        )
        
for i, o in enumerate(planes):
    o.location.z = (i + 1) * delta # local
    #o.matrix_world.translation.z = (i + 1) * delta # global
```

Or instead use selected objects

```
planes = sorted(
        context.selected_objects,
        key = lambda o : o.name
        )
```

Can sort on other criteria for example local  $x$ location

```
key = lambda o : o.location.x
```

area (assuming plane normal is local $z$ axis)

```
key = lambda o : o.dimensions.x * o.dimensions.y
```

Comment: .. which allows a regular riser, even given irregular treads. Oscurart Tools  would have done this, once..